# Google Sheets : Trying to get a price in one cell, depending on a product you choose in a different cell

Tags: google-sheets

So I am trying to create an easy google sheet, where our HR department can choose equipment to purchase for an individual employee.

[Here is an example of the sheet I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVmfr.png)

In the dropdown in one column you choose the Computer (column D), and I then want the price of the computer to appear in the column next to it (column E). All the prices are located in a separate sheet, so the values can be pulled from there.

So how in the world do I go about doing this? I have a feeling I might need to do a script, but I have NO knowledge or experience in terms of making scripts, which is why I am here :)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please, do not share images of your sheet. Especially since the data you want to use reside in another worksheet, we won't be able to provide any help. Share a public link to a Spreadsheet that resembles the structure of your original one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement and all major spread sheet applications should support this without having to resort to scripting.

You want to have a look at the [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) and [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) functions.

> Looks through a sorted row or column for a key and returns the value of the cell in a result range located in the same position as the search row or column.

Comment: Hmm I have no idea how to make that work with those functions? Could you help me out with actually providing the function phrase I would need to type in to get the desired result I am looking for. Because I just get "ERROR" after "ERROR" when I try, because as far as I gather, the search key has to be a number and cant be words like I need them to be.

Comment: The lookup can be a string. And there is an example on the documentation page. It's even with a price just like in your example.

Comment: So I found a video that explained some of it to me here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAzauT9DwkM

But when I follow her instructions, I get an error called VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range. What does this mean?